# Ktor: "could not find or load main class"

Tags: kotlin, server, ktor

I know similiar questions have already been asked but none of the solutions worked for me, so I gotta ask myself. I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project in which I'm trying to set up a server that does some web scraping for me. The problem is, when starting the server the program cant find main class "ApplicationKt" apparentely.

What I already tried: invalidate caches, restart laptop and android studio, run command with --warning-mode all (dont get any more information).

The error code:

```
> Task :server:run FAILED
Fehler: Hauptklasse de.takedown.ApplicationKt konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
Ursache: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.takedown.ApplicationKt

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':server:run'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java.exe' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My gradle file (server module):

```
val ktor_version = "2.3.8"
val htmlUnitVersion = "3.7.0"

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.ktor)
    application
}

application {
    // Entry Point
    mainClass.set("de.takedown.ApplicationKt")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dio.ktor.development=${extra["development"] ?: "false"}")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")

    // HTMLUNIT
    implementation("org.htmlunit:htmlunit:3.10.0")
}
```

Application.kt file code:

```
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                // example code
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

I'm really lost at what I'm doing wrong, would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the Kotlin JVM plugin to compile the Kotlin code.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.20" // version must be omitted if already on classpath
    alias(libs.plugins.ktor)
}
```

(It is not necessary to separately apply the Application plugin as this is applied by the Ktor plugin.)

Other things to also ensure that aren't clear from your question:

- Add the imports for all the Ktor classes to `Application.kt`
- Make sure `Application.kt` is in the `src/main/kotlin/de/takedown` folder

Comment: wow, you are a wizard, thank you so much! the plugins were the problem. i had to add     implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version") afterwards since I got a weird logoutput, but now everything seems to work :)

Comment: Nice :) I was looking at the examples in the documentation and was surprised that they don't show the Kotlin plugin being applied, which seems very misleading. If you saw the same thing and you're feeling motivated, it might be worth letting them know, because I don't see any way on this planet you can run Ktor without Kotlin to compile it